# Empty Result Set from Multi-Part Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query in which I am getting different information about encounters from two different queries, a third query will be added.

For each one of those queries I create a table for the records of that query to be inserted into, and at the end I create a sort of Master Answer Table, where I want to insert all records from the different tables into it.

It is possible that a person may not have a result being returned for all queries.

I think I am messing up my `join` in the final part of the query as I am getting TWO results, which I know is impossible. I am using SQL-Server 2008.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
-- VARIABLE DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME

-- THESE ARE PATIENT ADMIT DATES
SET @SD = '2013-01-01'
SET @ED = '2013-01-02'

-- @T1  ###############################################################
-- TABLE DECLARATION WHERE ALL RESULTS WILL GET DEPOSITED OF THE FIRST
-- QUERY WILL GET DEPOSITED. THIS TALBE WILL GET USED IN CONJUNCTION 
-- WITH TWO OTHER TABLES IN ORDER TO COMPUTE THE FINAL   
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
ENCOUNTER_ID VARCHAR(200)
, MRN VARCHAR(200)
, [PT AGE] VARCHAR(200)
, [PT NAME] VARCHAR(500)
, [DAYS STAY] VARCHAR(200)
, [LACE DAYS SCORE] VARCHAR(100)
, [ACUTE ADMIT SCORE] VARCHAR(100)
)
--#####################################################################

-- @T1 RECORD INSERTIONS ##############################################
INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT
A.PT_NO
, A.MED_REC_NO
, A.PT_AGE
, A.PT_NAME
, A.DAYS_STAY
, A.LACE_DAYS_SCORE
, A.ACUTE_ADMIT_LACE_SCORE
--#####################################################################

-- DAYS STAY, ACUTE ADMIT AND RELATED SCORING -------------------------
FROM
    (SELECT PT_NO
    , Med_Rec_No
    , Pt_Age
    , Pt_Name
    , Days_Stay
    , CASE
        WHEN Days_Stay < 1 THEN 0
        WHEN Days_Stay = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN Days_Stay = 2 THEN 2
        WHEN Days_Stay = 3 THEN 3
        WHEN Days_Stay BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 4
        WHEN Days_Stay BETWEEN 7 AND 13 THEN 5
        WHEN Days_Stay >= 14 THEN 6
      END AS LACE_DAYS_SCORE
    , CASE
        WHEN PLM_PT_ACCT_TYPE = 'I' THEN 3
      END AS ACUTE_ADMIT_LACE_SCORE

    FROM SMSDSS.BMH_PLM_PTACCT_V
    WHERE DSCH_DATE BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
    )A

--/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/--

-- @T2  ###############################################################
-- TABLE DECLARATION WHERE THE ER PORTION OF LACE SCORE FOR PATIENT
-- WILL GO.
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (
[MRN T2] VARCHAR(100)
, [PT NO] VARCHAR(20)
, [ER VISITS] VARCHAR (200)
, [ER VISITS LACE SCORE] VARCHAR(100)
)
--#####################################################################

-- @T2 RECORD INSERTIONS ##############################################
INSERT INTO @T2
SELECT B.MED_REC_NO
, B.Pt_No
, B.COUNT_MRN
, B.ER_LACE_SCORE
--#####################################################################

FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT Med_Rec_No
    , Pt_No
    , COUNT(Pt_No) AS COUNT_MRN
    , CASE
        WHEN COUNT(MED_REC_NO) = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN COUNT(MED_REC_NO) = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN COUNT(MED_REC_NO) = 2 THEN 2
        WHEN COUNT(MED_REC_NO) = 3 THEN 3
        WHEN COUNT(MED_REC_NO) >= 4 THEN 4
    END AS ER_LACE_SCORE

    FROM SMSDSS.BMH_PLM_PTACCT_V

    WHERE ADM_DATE >= '2013-01-01'
    AND (
        PLM_PT_ACCT_TYPE = 'I'
        AND ADM_SOURCE NOT IN
            ('RA',
            'RP'
            )
        )
    OR PLM_PT_ACCT_TYPE = 'E'
    GROUP BY MED_REC_NO, Pt_No
    )B
--/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/--

-- FINAL TABLE DECLARATION WHERE ALL INTERMEDIATE RESULTS GET DEPOSITED
DECLARE @LT TABLE (
ENCOUNTER_ID VARCHAR(200)
, MRN VARCHAR(200)
, AGE VARCHAR(30)
, NAME VARCHAR(500)
, LACE_DAYS_SCORE VARCHAR(100)
, LACE_ACUTE_ADM VARCHAR(100)
-- , LACE_COMORBID_SCORE VARCHAR(100)
, LACE_ER_VISITS VARCHAR(100)
)
-- ####################################################################

INSERT INTO @LT
SELECT
Q1.ENCOUNTER_ID
, Q1.MRN
, Q1.[PT AGE]
, Q1.[PT NAME]
, Q1.[LACE DAYS SCORE]
, Q1.[ACUTE ADMIT SCORE]
, Q1.[ER VISITS LACE SCORE]

FROM
(
SELECT
DISTINCT T1.ENCOUNTER_ID
, T1.MRN
, T1.[PT AGE]
, T1.[PT NAME]
, T1.[LACE DAYS SCORE]
, T1.[ACUTE ADMIT SCORE]
, T2.[ER VISITS LACE SCORE]

FROM @T1 T1
JOIN @T2 T2
ON T1.ENCOUNTER_ID = T2.[PT NO]
)Q1
--#####################################################################

SELECT *
FROM @LT
```

I have updated the code at @T2 to join on the encounter number since any Med_rec_no can have a theoretically infinite amount of encounter numbers. The Med_rec_no therefore can show up multiple times in the original dbo table and this is not a problem. The @T2 table is trying to count how many times a Med_rec_no has been to a certain place in the last 6 months, so it is dynamic, meaning if I come in today, then how many times have I been in the last six months including today.

I have made the code adjustments based on commetns that lead me in a better direction from the two who have commented on this post.

Comment: Are you SURE there can't be 2 entries from SMSDSS.BMH_PLM_PTACCT_V with the same Med_Rec_No?

Comment: there can surely be many rows where the MRN is the same. What I need to do and I did not make clear which I my fault is that this query will score a person each time they come in, so for example if I come in today and tomorrow then i will have two rows but each one of those rows will generate a score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure when you do

```
SELECT PT_NO
    , Med_Rec_No
    , Pt_Age
    , Pt_Name
    , Days_Stay
    , CASE
        WHEN Days_Stay < 1 THEN 0
        WHEN Days_Stay = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN Days_Stay = 2 THEN 2
        WHEN Days_Stay = 3 THEN 3
        WHEN Days_Stay BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 4
        WHEN Days_Stay BETWEEN 7 AND 13 THEN 5
        WHEN Days_Stay >= 14 THEN 6
      END AS LACE_DAYS_SCORE
    , CASE
        WHEN PLM_PT_ACCT_TYPE = 'I' THEN 3
      END AS ACUTE_ADMIT_LACE_SCORE
FROM SMSDSS.BMH_PLM_PTACCT_V
WHERE DSCH_DATE BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
```

There can be several rows with the same Med_Rec_No

Comment: Yes there can be multiple rows with the same med_rec_no, but each row constitutes a different visit. I am sorry I did not make this clear. Having multiple rows is fine, where it's getting tricky for me is scoring each individual encounter....I think I just hit something that is sending me back to the blackboard